# WCF with visual studio 2012

Tags: c#, .net, wcf, visual-studio

I am new WCF programming, I did followed series of Getting Started tutorials from following link

http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms734712.aspx

I have hosted service in console application but when I tried to create a client and tried to add service reference I got the following exceptions.

> There was an error downloading
>   'http:  localhost:8000/GettingStarted/mex/_vti_bin/ListData.svc/$metadata'.
>   The request failed with HTTP status 405: Method Not Allowed. Metadata
>   contains a reference that cannot be resolved:
>   'http:  localhost:8000/GettingStarted/mex'. There was no endpoint
>   listening at http:  localhost:8000/GettingStarted/mex that could
>   accept the message. This is often caused by an incorrect address or
>   SOAP action. See InnerException, if present, for more details. The
>   remote server returned an error: (404) Not Found. If the service is
>   defined in the current solution, try building the solution and adding
>   the service reference again.

code of hosting application

```cs
class Program
{
    static void Main(string[] args)
    {
        // Step 1 Create a URI to serve as the base address.
        Uri baseAddress = 
            new Uri("http://localhost:8000/GettingStarted/");

        // Step 2 Create a ServiceHost instance
        ServiceHost selfHost = 
            new ServiceHost(typeof(CalculatorService), baseAddress);

        try
        {
            // Step 3 Add a service endpoint.
            selfHost.AddServiceEndpoint(typeof(ICalculator), 
                new WSHttpBinding(), 
                "CalculatorService");

            // Step 4 Enable metadata exchange.
            var smb = new ServiceMetadataBehavior();
            smb.HttpGetEnabled = true;
            selfHost.Description.Behaviors.Add(smb);

            // Step 5 Start the service.
            selfHost.Open();
            Console.WriteLine("The service is ready.");
            Console.WriteLine("Press <ENTER> to terminate.");
            Console.WriteLine();
            Console.ReadLine();

            // Close the ServiceHostBase to shutdown.
            selfHost.Close();
        }
        catch (CommunicationException ce)
        {
            Console.WriteLine("exception: {0}", ce.Message);
            selfHost.Abort();
        }
    }
}
```

Now I am unable to figure out what the problem is. I am using visual studio 2012 and .net platform 4.5.

Comment: First of all were you able to successfully host a service? Can you share the output of your console application?

Answer (score 8, accepted):

I had a similar issue as well, messing with this.  Yes you seem to have followed the tutorial correctly, but if you want to connect to it and consume as a service (as in make a service reference) you must also add in the MEX service enpoint.  Add this line after your selfhost.Description.Behaviors.Add(smb):

```
selfhost.AddServiceEndpoint(
            typeof(IMetadataExchange),
            MetadataExchangeBindings.CreateMexHttpBinding(),
            "http://localhost:8000/GettingStarted/mex");
```

That should enable you to connect via "Add Service Reference".  Also, I have found depending on your system, you may need to run VS as admin to allow for connection to network (in case you accidentally told it no in the past).

Comment: I have the same error, how can I configure it via app.config instead of code?

Comment: I have same issue. Ijust checked config of service and I have this line <endpoint address="mex" binding="mexHttpBinding" contract="IMetadataExchange" /> is this the MEX service endpoint?

Comment: Why is this necassary when SoapUI can discover the service without any problems ? Only when I try to consume this (VS2015 project) service from VS2015, I run into this problem. But SoapUI can discover is without any problem.

Comment: Never mind, I had a different issue. I'll post my experience as an answer

Answer (score 0):

Judging from the error message it seems that there is no service listening at the specified port. You need to have the console application which hosts the service running when you are trying to add a service reference to it.

Comment: Hi Thanx for replying, Console application is running, but still same error

Comment: Also make sure that HttpGetEnabled is turned on in your service.  Otherwise your client won't be able to get the service contract.

Answer (score 0):

Apparently, the service is not running which means there is no endpoint listening at the URL you are using to create the service reference.

You can host the service in IIS, or keep the console application running as Damir mentioned above.

Answer (score 0):

Make sure your server is running when you are trying to access it. Also check the configuration on the server and make sure your client's endpoint matches the server's endpoint. Make sure you're using the same binding as well, while you're at it.
Make sure the server is listening and the server's firewall isn't blocking you. 
If you made a change to your WCF service don't forget to regenerate the service reference for your client application.

Comment: Hi console application was running, when i tried to add service reference

Answer (score 0):

Are you sure you have defined a MEX endpoint? This is what provides metadata information about your service, so that studio can generate a client proxy.

In the tutorial you linked to, it is [this bit](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms730935.aspx):

```
// Step 4 Enable metadata exchange.
ServiceMetadataBehavior smb = new ServiceMetadataBehavior();
smb.HttpGetEnabled = true;
selfHost.Description.Behaviors.Add(smb);
```

Comment: Yeah it is there in hosting application as u can see I have edited the question and it includes code of hosting application, should i post app.config as well?

Answer (score 0):

If you are hosting the web service in IIS, check in web.config(under behaviours section)

httpsGetEnabled is set to True

Answer (score 0):

I ran into a similar problem today. However, for me it wasn't needed for me to explicitly add the Endpoints, as @iMortalitySX already said.

I had a different reason for failing: I was binding to http://0.0.0.0, thinking the listen IP doesn't matter. Indeed, via SoapUI I **was** able to connect and to use the Service. But when trying to discover the service in another Visual Studio project, the discovery would fail, as VS would get the initial response, but then follow up links that contained http://0.0.0.0 and then fail.

So changing http://0.0.0.0 into the correct IP of my machine fixed my problem.

Answer (score -1):

Try put the uri address in Your browser. In my case I was able to see an ExceptionDetail.